# Unable to generate Oauth Authorization Code in Logic App

Tags: azure, authentication, oauth-2.0, azure-logic-apps, azure-data-catalog

We are going in the route of using ‘Azure logic app, http template’ to capture data from Azure SQL database and push the data into Azure Data Catalog. This is working in case we manually generate an authentication code and access token.  We need the authentication code and token to be generated automatically that can be used by logic app on schedule to post into ADC.

If anyone can provide me the details that will be really helpful

Looking forward for all your inputs

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add information into the Autentication parameter to generate an OAuth token assuming you just need an Azure AD token.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-http#authentication

Let me know if that works

Comment: We need to automatically generate Authentication code as well on schedule basis in Logic App